# Rails multiple render calls for ajax requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am working on a rails app in which I want to respond to ajax requests with a JSON object that contains both the instance variables that I have set in the Rails controllers by querying the database, as well as the rendered view (with no template). I am using an `after_filter` in the following way to accomplish this:

```
after_filter :handle_ajax
def handle_ajax

  respond_to do |format|

    format.html
    format.json do
      data = {}

      instance_variables.each {|iv| data[iv] = instance_variable_get(iv) }
      data[:url] = request.path
      #data[:html] = render_to_string :action => params[:action], :template => false

      render :json => data
    end

  end

end
```

However, Rails complains when I use this that I'm calling `render` twice (or in this case `render` and `render_to_string`). Is this not the correct way to go about handling ajax request? I'm relatively new to Rails, so it's quite possible that this just isn't the RoR way of doing things.

Comment: Try `render_to_string` with partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails calls render automatically for each action, you may try:

```
def index
  @tracks = @artist.tracks.find(:all, :limit => 10)
  render :nothing => true
end
```

EDIT (I don't think that works, actually): I would recommend to something like:

```
def index
  @tracks = @artist.tracks.find(:all, :limit => 10)
  handle_ajax :tracks => @tracks
end


def handle_ajax data
  respond_to do |format|

    format.html
    format.json do
      data[:url] = request.path

      render :json => data
    end
end
```

end

Comment: For anyone trying to do something similar to this: when you are responding to any other format than html, Rails tries to find templates based on that content type, so it will usually complain when you are trying to render an html template in the json block. The way to get around this is by adding `self.formats = ['html']` at the top of your `format.json do ... end` block

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the rest of your controllers methods are rendering their own as well. You can only have one render called. What does the rest of your controller look like?

Comment: The other actions don't call render, they basically just create instance variables from ActiveRecord queries. For example:
    `def index
        @tracks = @artist.tracks.find(:all, :limit => 10)
    end`

Do I need to call something in the action to tell rails not to automatically render the default view for this action?